# How to redirect all routes to index.html (Angular) in nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I am making Angular + NestJS app, and I want to send `index.html` file for all routes.

**main.ts**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'dist', 'my-app'));
  app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'dist', 'my-app'));
  await app.listen(port);
}
```

**app.controller.ts**

```
@Controller('*')
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  @Render('index.html')
  root() {
    return {};
  }
}
```

It works fine while I open `localhost:3000/`, but if I open `localhost:3000/some_route` the server falls with `500 internal error` and says `Can not find html module`.
I was searching why I am getting this error and everyone says `set default view engine like ejs or pug`, but I don't want to use some engines, I just want to send plain html built by angular without hacking like `res.sendFile('path_to_file')`. Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use `setBaseViewsDir` and `@Render()` with a view engine like handlebars (hbs); for serving static files (Angular), however, you can only use `useStaticAssets` and `response.sendFile`.

To serve `index.html` from all other routes you have a couple of possibilities:

### A) Middleware

You can create a middleware that does the redirect, see this [article](https://medium.com/@bo.vandersteene/use-nest-as-your-server-side-application-with-an-angular-frontend-540b0365bfa3):

```
@Injectable()
export class FrontendMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  resolve(...args: any[]): ExpressMiddleware {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve('../frontend/dist/my-app/index.html')));
    };
  }
}
```

and then register the middleware for all routes:

```
export class ApplicationModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewaresConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(FrontendMiddleware).forRoutes(
      {
        path: '/**', // For all routes
        method: RequestMethod.ALL, // For all methods
      },
    );
  }
}
```

### B) Global Error Filter

You can redirect all `NotFoundExceptions` to your `index.html`:

```
@Catch(NotFoundException)
export class NotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    response.sendFile(path.resolve('../frontend/dist/my-app/index.html')));
  }
}
```

and then register it as a global filter in your `main.ts`:

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new NotFoundExceptionFilter());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it could be easy if I could just set `useStaticAssets` and return files from `@Render()`. But it seems more complex than I thought.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but from where did you import the decorator @Middleware()?

Comment: @StefanKlocke A long, long time ago... https://docs.nestjs.com/v4/middlewares ;-) Nowadays it's just `@Injectable()`

Answer (score 4):

**Updated Answer for December 10, 2019**

*You need to create middleware for sending the react index.html*

Create middleware file

**frontend.middleware.ts**

```
import { NestMiddleware, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {Request, Response} from "express"
import { resolve } from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class FrontendMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    res.sendFile(resolve('../../react/build/index.html'));
  }
}
```

Include middleware in

**app.module.ts**

```
import { FrontendMiddleware } from './frontend.middleware';
import {
  Module,
  MiddlewareConsumer,
  RequestMethod,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
  configure(frontEnd: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    frontEnd.apply(FrontendMiddleware).forRoutes({
      path: '/**', // For all routes
      method: RequestMethod.ALL, // For all methods
    });
  }
}
```

**App Structure for Reference:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EYh7.png)

Comment: Ok Alan, but OP ask for Angular. I agree it's same.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cloud Functions for Firebase together with Firebase Hosting. What you have in **main.ts** is perfectly fine, with this approach you even don't need a controller. You should go as follows:

1. Rename `index.html` to `index2.html`. This is important to render your route path, otherwise you will have rendering working fine on all routes, excluding the root `/`.
2. Update `angular.json` to have the following `"index": "apps/myapp/src/index2.html",` (Simply change `index.html` to `index2.html`). **Note: path to the index.html might be different for you, I'm using [Nx](https://nx.dev) workspace**.
3. Add `templatePath: join(BROWSER_DIR, 'index2.html'),` to NestJS's `ApplicationModule`, most probably you name the file as **app.module.ts** in a **server** directory.

Like so:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
      bundle: require('./path/to/server/main'), // Bundle is created dynamically during build process.
      liveReload: true,
      templatePath: join(BROWSER_DIR, 'index2.html'),
      viewsPath: BROWSER_DIR
    })
  ]
})
```

4. Initialize Firebase Cloud Functions and Firebase Hosting, for how to set up this you can check https://hackernoon.com/deploying-angular-universal-v6-with-firebase-c86381ddd445 or https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-5-universal-firebase-4c85a7d00862
5. Edit your **firebase.json**.

It should look like that, or at least the `hosting` part.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "public": "functions/dist/apps/path/to/browser",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "function": "angularUniversalFunction",
        "source": "**"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

6. In your **main.ts** you need to set up Cloud Functions on your server.

In a minimialistic case it would like something like that:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

admin.initializeApp(); // Initialize Firebase SDK.
const expressApp: Express = express(); // Create Express instance.

// Create and init NestJS application based on Express instance.
(async () => {
  const nestApp = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    ApplicationModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(expressApp)
  );
  nestApp.init();
})().catch(err => console.error(err));

// Firebase Cloud Function for Server Side Rendering (SSR).
exports.angularUniversalFunction = functions.https.onRequest(expressApp);
```

With this approach you don't have to care about routes on the NestJS side. You can set up everything on the Angular side, and that's all. Angular takes care for routing. As you probably noticed this is Server-Side Rendering (SSR), but redirection of all routes to `index.html` (or more precisely `index2.html`) can be done using NestJS + Cloud Functions for Firebase in conjuction. Plus you have a SSR "for free" :)

Projects to showcase:

1) Angular + Angular Universal (SSR) + Cloud Functions for Firebase: https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular8-example-app (missing NestJS).

2) Angular + NestJS: https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/universal-nest (missing Cloud Functions for Firebase).