# How to serve static HTML files in Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, static-files

I want to serve static HTML files which are in a `/dist` folder outside of the Nest project. `index.html` is loaded successfully but it fails to load any JS file (`404` error).

I have a Node/Express.js project which uses

```
app.use('/', express.static('../client/dist'))
```

and it works perfectly fine.

In the Nest project, however,

```
app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '../../client/dist'))
```

does not do the trick.

In the `AppController` I tried

```
import { Response } from 'express';

@Get()
  get(@Res() res: Response) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {
      root: '../client/dist',
    });
  }
```

But no luck.

As mentioned, the `index.html` is loaded successfully. So the problem is not a wrong path. Neither is the problem wrong src-paths in the `index.html` because in the Express project the exact same files are used.

```
/dist
  |-index.html
  |-main.js
  |-etc.
```

In the index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

It does not work either when I put the dist folder into the Nest project (and adapt the path).

### I found the solution:

I use the express module now:

```
import * as express from 'express';
...
app.use('/', express.static('../client/dist'));
```

Comment: Still open questions? :-)

Comment: @KimKern No, thank you. I was able to solve it with the solution mentioned above :-)

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. :-) In general, consider adding your solution as an answer instead of updating your question so others can profit from it. Then you can accept your answer to show others your problem was solved. In this case, I'd suggest using the nest API instead of the native express api though, see my solution.

Comment: For Angular + NestJS + Cloud Functions for Firebase see the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493387/11127383

Comment: +1 for moving your found solution into an own answer! Don't know why, but useStaticAssets did not work for me but your solution did. And I only found your solution after reading all answers twice.

Answer (score 19):

For serving static files you have to use `useStaticAssets()` instead of `setBaseViewsDir()`:

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '../../client/dist'))
```

---

When you use `useStaticAssets` you don't need to set up a controller, all your files will be served automatically:

Let's say under `client/dist` you have the files `index.html` and `pic.jpg`.
They will be served as:

```
localhost:3000 -> index.html
localhost:3000/pic.jpg -> pic.jpg
```

---

Setting the base views dir is needed when you want to use a view engine like for example `hbs`, see [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc).

Comment: That threw me off big time.  Thank you!

Comment: Note you need to cast app to the correct type:
`const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);`
to get correct typing in typescript.

Answer (score 19):

Regarding the [official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static) of Nest.js one should serve static files like this:

Install the required package:

```
npm install --save @nestjs/serve-static
```

Update [app.module.ts](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/24-serve-static/src/app.module.ts) to look like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client'),   // <-- path to the static files
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I used it as described. But the browser still targets the backend. Is there any information, which tells me, if the serveStatic works?

Answer (score 8):

If you have something like this

```
/public
  |-index.html
  |-main.js
  |-etc.
/src
  |-app.controller.js
  |-app.module.js
  |-main.js
```

In main.ts or main.js

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  app.setViewEngine('html');

  await app.listen(5000);
}
bootstrap();
```

In app.module.js

```
@Module({
  imports: 
  [ 
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
      exclude: ['/api*'],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In app.controller.js

```
@Controller()
@Dependencies(AppService)
export class AppController {
  constructor(appService) {
    this.appService = appService;
  }

  @Get()
  @Render('index')
  root() {
  }
}
```

With this code, you can do the trick :) :) :)

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to do it in "main.ts" **or** "app.module.ts" (you don't need them both), it's better for you to add "prefix" option in the "main.ts":

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'), {prefix: '/public'});
```

Or the "serveRoot" option in the "app.module.ts":

```
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
   serveRoot: '/public',
   rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
}),
```

And make the link to your static files as "[your host]/public/[your dir and files]"
To divide your static path than other paths.

Answer (score 2):

Write `app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '../../client/dist'))` in main.ts

And also you can try for fastify app this:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';

app.useStaticAssets({
    root: resolve("./build")
});
```

Comment: That's incorrect. When you use `useStaticAssets` you don't need any controller. The files will be served automatically, `index.html` will be accessible under the root path.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I want to serve the public images through API, so I tried the below approach:

**Create a constant to configure the public folder:**

```
// src\constants\constant.ts
export const PUBLIC_IMAGES = 'public/images';
```

**Add ServeStaticModule in your app.module.ts:**

```
// src\app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';
import { PUBLIC_IMAGES } from './constants/constant';

@Module({
 imports: [
  ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
   serveRoot: '/public',
   rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', PUBLIC_IMAGES),
  })
 ],
 controllers: [],
 providers: [ ],
})


export class AppModule {}
```

**Create a public folder for your images:**

```
root->public\images\myImage.png
```

**Hit URL in the browser:**

```
http://localhost:3010/public/myImage.png
```