# NestJS deliver static files based on language of browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, nestjs, i18next

Nestjs should deliver an Angular application based on the language defined in the browser.

The Angular application is located on `dist/public/en` or `dist/public/de`.

If the user is accessing `/` with an English browser, nestjs should deliver files from folder `dist/public/en`. The path in the browser should point in this case to `fqdn/en/`.

I already use this with single language Angular App:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, 'public'));
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

I also had a look into [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware) which looks promising.

But I'm not really sure if this is the right direction to go.

Any tip is warmly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kim-kern thanks a lot for your answer. It pushed me into the right direction.

I solved the problem now the following way:
maint.ts will do language detection based on a global middleware and defines a static delivery of files:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { join } from 'path';
const i18next = require('i18next');
const middleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  i18next.use(middleware.LanguageDetector).init({
    detection: {
      order: ['path', 'session', 'querystring', 'cookie', 'header'],
    },
  });

  app.use(
    middleware.handle(i18next, {
      ignoreRoutes: ['/api'],
      removeLngFromUrl: false,
    }),
  );

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, 'public'));
  app.use(compression());
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

I defined a custom middleware that checks for the found language and based on the baseUrl it delivers the correct index.html file:

```js
import { NestMiddleware, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class FrontendMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: Response, next: Function) {
    if (req.lng && !req.baseUrl && req.lng.startsWith('de')) {
      res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'public', 'de', 'index.html'));
    } else if (!req.baseUrl) {
      res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'public', 'en', 'index.html'));
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

The custom middleware is then included in the app.module.ts:

```js
...
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(FrontendMiddleware).forRoutes({
      path: '/**',
      method: RequestMethod.ALL,
    });
  }
}
```

The only problem that is open is now that it tries to deliver the files always from the fixed directory public which fails if running in development and not production mode.

I will search there for a solution for it.

Comment: fyi: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware has been deprecated and replaced with https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware

Answer (score 1):

Better than serving your `dist` folder statically would be to redirect ***all*** non-api routes to `index.html` so that your Angular SPA can take care of the routing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54840961/4694994) for more details.

---

You can adapt the middleware from the linked answer above by taking the factors into account with which you want to detect the user's language e.g. the `ACCEPT-LANGUAGE` header or a certain cookie:

```
@Middleware()
export class FrontendMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    // Some way of detecting the user's language
    const languages = req.header('ACCEPT-LANGUAGE') || 'en-US';

    if (languages.contains('de-DE')) {
      res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'public', 'de' ,'index.html'));
    } else {
      res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'public', 'en', 'index.html'));
    }
  }
}
```